# Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)+x} = 2 \pi$ for some $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)+x}$ for $x>0$ contains a value c such that $f(c)=2\pi$.

It seems like this is somehow related to the fact that 
$$1-1/3+1/5-...=\pi/4$$
but I can't figure out how to manipulate the proof for that equation to align with this problem.

I know that I can use the Mean Value Theorem to show this since when $x$ approaches $0$, the sum is 1. I just need to show that a value for $x$ exists so that $f(x)>2\pi$.

Comment: $f(x)$ goes to infinity as $x\to 0$ since the $n=0$ term gets arbitrarily large. So you actually need to work to show that for some $x$, $f(x) < 2\pi$.

Comment: @MarkFischler and... continuity. It's a bit of an important detail.

Comment: "[**Your question should be clear without the title.**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title." I have [edited your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2431186/revisions) to reflect this principal.

Comment: What about you define f ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = \sum_0^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)+x}$$.
Then for all $x>0$
$$
f(x) \leq \frac1x + \sum_1^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)+x}  \leq \frac1x + \sum_1^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)} $$

In particular,
$$
f(1) \leq 1+ \sum_1^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)} = 1+1 = 2 < 2\pi
$$
On the other hand, 
$$f(\frac18) =8+ \sum_1^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)+\frac18} >8 > 2\pi
$$
then by the intermediate value theorem, ther is some $c$ in $[1,8]$ such that $f(c) = 2\pi$.

To be rigorous, you also actually need to prove that $f(x)$ is continuous, and that is somewhat harder.

Comment: It converges uniformly since for any $x>0$, the series is $\le 1/n^2$, so by Weierstrass M test it converges uniformly, and since each $f_n$ is continuous, the limit function is also continuous

Comment: Can't you merely compute ${df(x) \over d x}$ to see that it is well-behaved and continuous?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How do you do that, though?

Comment: @ClementC:  The derivative is a linear operator, so apply it to each of the terms and sum them:  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{(n (n+1)+x)^2}$.

Comment: Nope. Infinitely many terms -- for that to work, you need extra assumptions... a sufficient condition would include... uniform convergence.

Comment: @ClementC. If course, UC of the series of differentiated terms is trivial for $x\in [x_0,\infty).$ for $x_0>0$.

Comment: @ClementC. "A sufficient condition...would include uniform convergence" of the original series or the derived series?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Of the series of termwise derivatives. (cf usual theorem,s e.g. Theorem 2 [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf)). The point is, one cannot just wing it saying "differentiation is linear, let's swap $\sum$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$."

Answer (score 3):

Starting from your initial idea of : $\quad \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac 13+\frac 15-...$

We can write :

$$2\pi=8\times\frac{\pi}4=8\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac {8}{4n+1}-\frac {8}{4n+3}\right)\\\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {16}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {16}{16n^2+16n+3}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n(n+1)+\frac 3{16}}$$

Thus $f(\frac 3{16})=2\pi$

Comment: Very nice computation, Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

The sum is uniformly convergent on each interval $[\epsilon, 1]$ with $\epsilon > 0$ and thus converges to a continuous function there. Furthermore, it is clearly decreasing on $(0, 1]$ and unbounded as $x\to 0$. Since
\begin{align*}
f(1) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1) + 1} \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = 2 < 2\pi,
\end{align*}
it follows that $f(x) = 2\pi$ for some $x\in (0, 1]$.

Answer (score -1):

A possible direct solution using Maple is as follows.

The series is computed as

$$f(x)=\frac{\displaystyle\pi\tan\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{1-4x}}2\right)}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$

Then we get the equation

$$\frac{\displaystyle\pi\tan\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{1-4c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{1-4c}}=2\pi$$

and the corresponding solution is $$ c = 0.187500$$.

Do you agree?

Comment: And how did you calculate said result?

Comment: Hi @SimplyBeautifulArt,  thanks for editing my post.  I am using Maple.

Comment: Well, not exactly a proof to my eyes unless you showed how Maple got there. Especially since the original function is defined on $(0,1/4]$ while yours is not.

Comment: The closed form that Maple provides is defined on $x = 1/4$, namely $$f(1/4) = {\pi }^{2}/2$$.  Do you agree?

Comment: No, since plugging in $1/4$ gives $0/0$. What you probably mean is the limit as $x\to1/4^+$

Comment: Yes I mean such limit.