# Continuity of $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)+x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that $f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ is a well-defined and continuous function, where
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)+x}.$$

I'm not exactly sure what it means for a function to be well-defined, but for continuity I was thinking of showing that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test and then concluding that since $f(x)$ can be differentiated term by term, the derivative $f'(x)$ exists which implies continuity.

Does this work?

Comment: Related to (spawned from) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431186/show-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1nn1x-2-pi-for-some-x0/2431192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think well-defined just means $f(x) \in (0,\infty)$.

Your argument about differentiation is  unnecessary. Observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1) +x} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$. So, the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1) +x}$ converge uniformly to $f$, and each is continuous. Now you can conclude.

Comment: You do realize the sum starts at 0, right?

Comment: (I.e., you can use your argument, but then also handle the additional $1/x $ in your proof.)

Comment: I didn't realize no, oops. It should be a simple modification though.

Comment: Yes. $f=g+h$, where $g(x)=1/x$ and $h(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)$. Your argument deals with continuity of $h$; continuity of $g$ is... obvious.

Answer (score 2):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)+x}=\frac{\pi  \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}   \sqrt{1-4 x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}$$

Comment: Here is a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521600/methods-for-evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-frac1an-1n/3521601#3521601