# Solving $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{6n\left(n-1\right)\ +\ 1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> How to solve the following sum?
> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{6n\left(n-1\right)\ +\ 1}$$

I was learning about [Star Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_number#:%7E:text=The%20last%20two%20digits%20of,are%20also%20consecutive%20star%20numbers.) then I saw on wikipedia that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{S_n} = \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)$ where $S_n$ denotes the star number. I really don't know how to solve this sum.

---

I tried to approximate the infinite sum using integral,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{6n\left(n-1\right)\ +\ 1}\ dn$$
But this seems not working here.

---

I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3521601/983206) is quite relevant but I want to know any approach using some elementary techniques.

Comment: What's the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), btw?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I don't think partial fraction decomposition would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, knowing the solution makes it simpler.  Found
$$
\pi \tan \pi x = 2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+\tfrac12)^2 - x^2}=:f(x)
\tag 1$$
in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion), so let's work towards that:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{6n(n-1)+1}
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{6n^2+6n+1}\\
&=\frac 16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{n^2+n+\frac14-\frac14+\frac16}\\
&=\frac 16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{(n+\frac12)^2-\frac 1{12}}\\ 
&=\frac16\cdot \frac{f(1/\sqrt{12})}{2\cdot1/\sqrt{12}}\\
&=\frac 1 {\sqrt{12}} \,f\Big(\frac 1 {\sqrt{12}}\Big)
\end{align}$$

So what's left is to show the partial fraction expansion $(1)$, but that's a much more common and generic result from Euler, and proof should be easy to find. For example, here is [Cotangent and the Herglotz Trick](https://www-m9.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/WS2010/IMCSeminar/Cotangent.pdf) as PDF. Or here at MSE there is [How did Euler prove the partial fraction expansion of the cotangent function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1849878/746312).